# Extrude edge and slide

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there a way to slide along edge after extrude an edge, similar to slide when loop cutting.
Currently one need to slide selected edges and after that use loop cut to recreate previous geometry.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, are you wanting to repeat an extrusion, or loop cut and slide while extruding? Maybe adding images to show an example highlighting what you are after would help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure I understand, but you can recreate the edge slide from a loop cut by selecting the edge, keying *G*, and then *G* again, and moving the cursor. This gif shows the difference between *G* and *G, G*:

[image]