# Extrude while sliding

Tags: edges, extrude

I learned about the slide operation on edges. I use it to select a border edge loop, press gg and then hold alt to slide and increase the size of the border faces. Now I'd like to use this while extruding, rather than moving the edges. I want to keep the original edges and faces, but get a new row of faces along the selected border edge loop. The new border edge loop would be the result of sliding as usual, only the old loop is still there.

Note I don't want to slide the border edge loop to be in the new position and then have to recreate a new loop at the old position.

For example the following shape, viewed head-on orthographically.

[image]

Say I want to extrude the selected edges by sliding them. Extruding and immediately scaling is no good: (e, escape, s)

[image]

Instead I want to extrude along the lines also used for sliding: (gg, hold alt)

[image]

However I want to keep the old edges too. I want to add a new row of faces, the same as when extruding, but the shape of those faces is determined the same way as when sliding.

I hope I make myself clear. I think [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52349/extrude-edge-and-slide) is asking the exact same, however they did not get a correct answer.

Cheers!

Comment: I suggest adding pictures to illustrate what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To scale the outer loopcut (like [*Edge Slide*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-slide) with *Clamping* enabled does) scale along normals.
Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel. There were created double vertices which have the same position as their parent vertices.
Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale along normals.

[image: GIF scaling along normals]

Note that after the scale procedure is done scaling won't provide the same result as normals' orientation for newly extruded vertices changed; they will move towards the view point because of that (*Edge Slide* will work instead).

Comment: That did the trick! But only after recalculating my normals (ctrl+n and ctrl+shift+n).

Comment: I might have spoken too soon. On my actual project, I get this result: http://i.imgur.com/yskNLsI.png The edges are not extruding along the sliding lines, which would be like this: http://i.imgur.com/bgv6D3j.png Any tips?

Comment: It was set to Median Point, Bounding Box gives the same result

Comment: Looking at the normals, they seem to be the problem. http://i.imgur.com/pyrg8r3.png For what I want, the normals should be pointing along the direction of the interior edges. I don't know why the normals are pointing in the direction that they are.

Comment: Those normals seem to be created when I perform the extrusion. The normals of the original edges seem fine.

Comment: @Marein scaling like this can happen if near geometry already has some shift along any of the axis; it seems this changes vectors' direction. Newly added vertices indeed have another vector of the normals, hence sliding along original ones (from your question) is easier. This doesn't seem to be a bug but strange.

Comment: Thanks. How do I slide along the original though? In my question I show how to slide the original vertices, but then I lose their position. Is there a way to keep the old vertices, create new ones, and slide them along the normals of the old vertices?

Comment: @Marein it's not possible afaik. You can scale along normal of any selected element (vertex etc) if setting Pivot to Active and selecting that element as the last one; Transform Orientation will also be very important. However scaling along normals uses their own normals.

Comment: Shame, there doesn't seem to be a technical reason. Seems like it would be a good feature to add. Thanks for the info!